# tilemill - styling map similar to google at max out zoom level

Tags: tilemill

I have osm bright in tilemill
When i zoom all the way out to the world, the style on the maps looks very bland and basic, I was hoping to achieve something like how google maps look (I'm not after a direct copy), also mapquest has something similar

I.e. when you zoom all the way out, google maps looks a bit more interesting (nicer colours and shading) instead of one bland colour

My questions are
1) is there something open source that already has a less bland style (not sat photo view) - use google maps max zoom out to see what i mean

2) is it possible to combine my existing osmbright skin with something else but which only kicks in at certain zoom levels ?

Edit
Here is a good example of something i'd like
https://cloud.maptiler.com/customize/#streets/0.76/0/120.5